# remove leading 0s with stringr in R

Tags: r, stringr

I have the following data

```
id
00001
00010
00022
07432
```

I would like to remove the leading `0`s so the data would like like the following

```
id
1
10
22
7432
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Using the new `str_remove` function in `stringr`:

```
id = str_remove(id, "^0+")
```

Comment: For posterity, I had to update my `stringr` version to `1.3.0`

Answer (score 14):

We can just convert to `numeric`

```
as.numeric(df1$id)
[#1]    1   10   22 7432
```

---

If we require a `character` class output, `str_replace` from `stringr` can be used

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(df1$id, "^0+" ,"")
#[1] "1"    "10"   "22"   "7432"
```

Comment: What does the "^0+" part mean?

Comment: @Basil The `+` implies one or more, so if the 0 is prefix, it would be one or more zeros and the `^` suggest the start of the string.  Therefore, the pattern checked is one or more zeros as the beginning of a string

Answer (score 12):

Here is a base R option using `sub`:

```
id <- sub("^0+", "", id)
id

[1] "1"    "10"   "22"   "7432"
```

### Demo